# If $\int_0^{x/3} f(t)dt =\int_0^xf(t)dt$, prove $f$ is identically $0$

Tags: real-analysis

$f:[0,1] \to \mathbf R$ is continuous. If $$\int_0^{x/3} f(t)dt =\int_0^xf(t)dt$$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$, prove that $f$ is identically $0$.

My thought is to prove that the maximum and minimum of $f$ are equal then $f$ is constant and this constant can only be zero. But I can't think of a way to do that. Can somebody help and give me some hints. Thanks.

Comment: My thought is to look at $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{dt}$ as a continuous and differentiable function, satisfying $F(x) = F(x/3)$.

Comment: Are you sure $x\in[0,1]$ ? I think it will be $x>0$

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: I believe in this case $f(t)$ need only be defined on $[0,1]$ and thus only on that interval do we need to argue it is identically zero.

Comment: It must be $x\in (0,1]$..Otherwise the statement is FALSE

Comment: @S.Panja-1729:  Why would the statement be false?  Do you have a counterexample where it is true for all $x\in (0,1)$ but false if we require the condition as well for endpoints $x=0,1$?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 No. It also holds for $f(0)=0$.

Comment: If we take $x=0$ and $f(x)=5$ then the relation holds but $f\not \equiv 0$

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: be careful that the supposition is on *all* $x \in [0,1]$, not just a particular point. Your $f$ certainly doesn't satisfy that.

Comment: @6005:  Often the extensive use of $\LaTeX$ in titles will cause formatting problems, esp. when a post gets on the Hot Questions list and is displayed on SE sites which do not support MathJax.

Comment: @hardmath The title should be descriptive of the actual problem to be solved. Otherwise, you have to click on it to find out. Which is a big pain in the behind in pretty much any context--looking for a problem to answer, finding duplicates, locating a question that you previously answered or referenced, etc. I know about LaTeX having some formatting problems in titles, but I think having a descriptive title is a bigger concern. Otherwise we have ten questions all named "prove $f$ is identically zero" and they're all different. (In fact, I see four or five such questions in the side bar.)

Comment: I also don't much care for the hot networks question list, I think it sucks, and I hope we get less clicks from it. Anyway it is not our problem if people don't display our titles correctly.

Comment: It's easy to show F is constant, see my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

FTC $\implies \frac13 f(x/3) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

Added:

Which in turn gives:

$$\frac1{3^n} f\left(\frac1{3^n}x\right) = f(x), \ \forall \ x \in [0,1], \ n \in \mathbb N$$

Comment: Expand please..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 f is *uniformly* continuous so for small x we must have $f(x)=0$ (and for x=0 too)

Comment: If we take $x=0$ and $f(x)=5$ then the relation holds but $f\not \equiv 0$

Comment: @S.Panja-1729:  The problem stipulates (among other things) that $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Comment: So what? $f$ is constant function and that equal to $5$.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729:  That makes no sense.  The integral of $f(x)\equiv 5$ on $[0,1]$ is $5$, which is not equal to $\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}} 5 dt = 5/3$.

Comment: I take $x=0$....

Comment: @S.Panja-1729:  You seem to be ignoring the fact that $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$.  You need to specify values on the entire domain of $f$ to provide a counterexample.

Comment: I edited your post a little to make the parentheses wrap around the argument of $f$. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: Very nicely done!  +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{dt}, x \in [0,1]$ be a primitive of $f$.

Taking  $x \in [0, 1]$, from $F(x)=F(x/3)$ we get (by recursively changing $x \rightarrow x/3$) $F(x)=F(x/3^{n}), \forall n \in \mathbf N$. Because F continous and $(x/3^n) \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have  $F(x)=F(0)$. Therefore F is constant and $f = F'= 0$

Answer (score 1):

Expand @BolzWeir's answer.

First I propose to show that $f(0)=0$:

Due to the equality we have
$$\int_{x/3}^x f =0$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$. Note that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, which is to say, for an $\epsilon>0$ we can find a uniform $\delta>0$ that suits all $x\in [0,1]$. Suppose $f(0)=a> 0$, then let $\epsilon=a/2$, and take an arbitrary $x\in(0,\delta)$, we would have
$$\int_{x/3}^x f >a/2\cdot 2x/3>0$$
a contradiction. The case where $a<0$ is handled similarly.

By continuity, it means $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$. And for all $x\in[0,1]$, based on @BolzWeir's answer 
$$3^nf(x)=f(\frac x{3^n})\to 0\quad \text{as}\, n\to\infty$$
which indicates $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Well, uniform continuity seems to be unnecessary, pointwise at 0 is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

It is straightforward to see from the hypotheses that
$\int_0^x f = \int_0^{x \over 3^n} f$ for any $n$ and, taking limits, that
$\int_0^x f = 0$ for any $x$. In particular, it follows that
$\int_a^b f = \int_0^b f -\int_0^a f = 0$ and hence (reasoning by contradiction on a suitably small interval) that $f = 0$.

If $f$ is just integrable, the above reasoning can be extended to show that $f(x) = 0$ for ae. $x$.